# how to get access token from redirect uri in android

Tags: support, android

I enabled both client side flow and desktop oauth redirect url, and manage to get the user login and get redirected to https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=xxxxx

But how can i manage this webview and parse from android... my activity from the android manifest manages the data url like  but nothing is happening...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a data filter for the activity that you call the authentication URL in the manifest like:

```
<data   android:host="stackexchange.com" 
        android:pathPrefix="/oauth/login_success" 
        android:scheme="https" 
/>
```

The activity also needs to override the `onResume` function for you to parse the URL and get the access token from the URI.